# change axis measure with vincent library and python

Tags: python, vincent

I would create a plot with the distribution of an hashtag during a determinate time. When I have done it I have discover that the measure of y axis was wrong, it sets to be a decimal measure, not an ordinal measure:[image]

All my values are bigger than 1, the most high value of my y axis. What can I do?
This is my code used to make the plot:

```
time_chart = vincent.Line(malaria)
time_chart.axis_titles(x='Time', y='Freq')
time_chart.to_json('time_chart.json')
time_chart.to_json('time_chart.json', html_out=True, html_path='timechart.html')
```